# Відповідник до слова "дауншифтинг"

Tags: іменники, відповідник

Є доволі гарне слово, однак запозичене. Про нього читаємо у [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=213315&page=709)

> **ДАУНШИ́ФТИНГ**, у, ч. Зміна способу життя на менш напружений завдяки зміщенню життєвих цінностей заради себе чи сім'ї.

Однак щось мене зацікавило, чи є власне український відповідник до цього слова, що відповідав би його семантиці.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/daunshyftyng) знаходимо такі відповідники:

> Сковородинство, простожиття, простішництво,  відмежувальництво, життєспрощення, аскеза,  попущення, спрощення, простожитство, опускальництво, себелюбство, самовідмова.

Слова, що їх уподобали найбільше: **сковородинство, просто життя, простішництво, відмежувальництво, життєспрощення** – немає в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/). Інші слова, якщо навіть є у словниках, то користувачі цього сайту вважають, що вони не приживуться в постійному вжитку .

Comment: *сковородинство* - це круто:)

Comment: Додам, що [«Редакторський портал»](http://redactor.in.ua/ru/language/6763.kult_movi_yak_pereklasti_selfі) приписує вищепаведений варіант _простішництво_ [Дмитру Шостаку](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шостак_Дмитро_Сергійович): «Цю ініціативу підхоплює дитячий поет Дмитро Шостак. „Від «жити простіше»: простішництво, простішник, стати простішником“, — пропонує він», — пише портал. (І саме з посиланням на «Редакторський портал» цей варіант було додано до «Словотвору».) Хоча на практиці я поки що вживань цього варіанту не бачив: ані в творах Д. Шостака, ані деінде.

Comment: За «сковородинство» можна сказати, що воно де-факто вживається: [1](//theukrainians.org/skovorodyntsi/), [2](//news.agro-center.com.ua/eco-farming/molod-u-seli-para-daunshiftery.html), [3](//www.tenews.org.ua/post/view/1526928513-kazka-pro-vedmedicyu). Проти можна сказати, що це слово вживається не лише на позначення давншифтингу, а й на позначення інших рис, характерних для Г. Сковороди та його творчості: [1](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=h-2PAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=сковородинство), [2](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=H0lGBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=сковородинство), …

Comment: …[3](http://static.klasnaocinka.com.ua/uploads/editor/12043/660665/sitepage_12/files/049012639.pdf), [4](http://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/3273/188/120516/), [5](http://citylife.com.ua/index.php?id=33&tid=381&art=558), [6](http://tyzhden.ua/history/67626), [7](http://litlife.club/br/?b=259617&p=31), [8](//mamache.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/оксана-забужко-ділюся-своїм-шевченко/) — причому й у книжках.